# How to Zoom in/out imageView on Click using java in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, zooming

i have followed this tutorial to zoom in `imageview` on touch but i have an activity that have 15 images and when i click on any one image it will open new Activity and will zoom in that clicked image on new Activity so my question is

1. How can i pass clicked image src to nextActivity so that my single method will be applicable to zoom in for all images.
2. On new Activity (Zoom in)  when i clicked on it how can i zoom out that image again.
   I have followed this:[Zoom in](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/05/zoom-image-demo-in-android-zoom-image.html?)

Its successfully zoom in an `imageview` but i have no idea how to write code for zoom out.Can someone please help me on this task.

Any Tutorials will be appreciated but link must contain  same code as it is in this url with some few changes for zoom out

Comment: Have a look on this http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {
        Matrix matrix;
        static final int NONE = 0;
        static final int DRAG = 1;
        static int ZOOM = 2;
        static int mode = NONE;
        public  int isundo = 0;
        PointF last = new PointF();
        PointF start = new PointF();
        float minScale = 0f;
        float maxScale = 1f;
        float[] m;
        int viewWidth, viewHeight;
        static final int CLICK = 3;
        float saveScale = 1f;
        protected float origWidth, origHeight;
        int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
        float bmWidth, bmHeight;
        ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
        Context context;
        public TouchImageView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            if (isundo == 0) {
                sharedConstructing(context);
            }
        }

        public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            if (isundo == 0) {
                sharedConstructing(context);
            }
        }

        private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {

            super.setClickable(true);
            this.context = context;
            mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
            matrix = new Matrix();
            m = new float[9];
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
            setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
            setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                    PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    if (isundo == 0) {
                        switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            last.set(curr);
                            start.set(last);
                            mode = DRAG;

                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            if (mode == DRAG) {
                                float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                                float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                                matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                                fixTrans();
                                last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                            }
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                            int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                            if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                                performClick();
                            break;

                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                            mode = NONE;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    invalidate();
                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }

            });

        }

        public void stopInterceptEvent() {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        public void startInterceptEvent() {
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
            super.setImageBitmap(bm);
            if (bm != null) {
                origWidth = bm.getWidth();
                origHeight = bm.getHeight();
            }
        }

        public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
            maxScale = x;
        }

        private class ScaleListener extends
                ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                mode = ZOOM;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
                float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
                float origScale = saveScale;
                saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
                if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                    saveScale = maxScale;
                    mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
                } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                    saveScale = minScale;
                    mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
                }

                if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                        || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                            viewHeight / 2);
                else
                    matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                            detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

                fixTrans();
                return true;
            }
        }

        void fixTrans() {
            matrix.getValues(m);
            float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
            float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

            float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
            float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                    * saveScale);

            if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
                matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
        }

        float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            float minTrans, maxTrans;

            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                minTrans = 0;
                maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            } else {
                minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
                maxTrans = 0;
            }

            if (trans < minTrans)
                return -trans + minTrans;
            if (trans > maxTrans)
                return -trans + maxTrans;
            return 0;
        }

        float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
            if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
                return 0;
            }
            return delta;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
            viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            //
            // Rescales image on rotation
            //
            if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                    || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
                return;
            oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
            oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

            if (saveScale == 1) {
                // Fit to screen.
                float scale;

                Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
                if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                        || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                    return;
                int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

                float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
                float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
                scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
                matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

                // Center the image
                float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                        - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
                float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                        - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
                redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
                redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

                matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

                origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
                origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
                setImageMatrix(matrix);
            }
            fixTrans();
        }
    }





use this way like ::---->>>



TouchImageView iv = new TouchImageView(getApplicationContext());
                iv.setImageBitmap(editedImage);

                layout.addView(iv);
```

Comment: may i need to define anything in xml ?

Comment: this class add to your package and just add touchimageview to your layout and start work..

Comment: how can i get imageView image name on click of ImageView ?

Comment: how to set image name dynamically in this code using iv.setImageResource()   ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45924/discussion-between-erum-hannan-and-user2968888)

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");  this for get image from camera . you can set dynamic image as u want from anywhere

Comment: i need to display more Layout along with this imageView zoom effect how can i do that its only loading that zoom image