# How to Zoom in/out imageView

Tags: android

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21301894/how-to-zoom-in-out-imageview-on-click-using-java-in-android/36080170?noredirect=1#comment59804848_36080170) code.

I have a problem.
I need zoom image and I changed in code:

[image]

original image is:

[image]

but on portrait is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

and on landscape it is:

[image: ![enter image description here]

It's not full screen. Why?

Comment: use to "android:scaleType="fitXY" " for set the image in Imageview

Answer (score 1):

Use this custome imageview for pinchzoom in out

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/ortiz/touch/TouchImageView.java

it work for me.hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try PhotoViewAttacher. Works wonderfully well. You need not change the ImageView, you just need to attach your imageView as explained. I use this in one of my applications and it works very well.

https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

Comment: The code was introduced, aren't need ID for image. do not need to put this image in layout.

Comment: I believe you mean to say that the ImageView you have is created by code and NOT by layout. If you are using this ImageView generated by code to customize your Zoom, you can achieve the same by using normal ImageView given by Android framework and then attach the PhotoView to make that Zoom.